# How to display all day events in Timeline view?

Tags: fullcalendar

Is there a way to make the all-day area appear in Timeline view?

I guess I could assign all resourceId's to all day events, but that seams a little bit of an overkill....

Comment: That all-day slot is a specific feature of the timeGrid view, as far as I know. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/allDaySlot describes the option to enable it. There is no equivalent option for timeline view.

Comment: @ADyson thank you. If that's the case, a follow up question: is there a way to have an all-resource event? something like resourceIds:[all] which will make the event appear on all resources without the need to add all resources to it?

Comment: Not as far as I know. You could try [requesting it](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features)